# Deploying Data Factory through ARM - Data Factory not recognizing Stored Procedure

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-factory

On deploying my ARM for my Data Factory, it is not recognizing my stored procedure and giving this value as my **'Stored procedure name'**: `[object Object]`

[image]

Here is how my stored procedure is declared in **ARM Template**:

```js
{
        "name": "execute_teststoredproc",
        "type": "SqlServerStoredProcedure",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "policy": {
            "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
            "retry": 0,
            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
            "secureOutput": false,
            "secureInput": false
        },
        "userProperties": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "storedProcedureName": {
                "value": "[[dbo].[teststoredproc]"
            }
        },
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "TargetSQLDB",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        }
    }
```

Anyone knows why this is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you cannot use the `value` field for `storedProcedureName`. Simple yet subtle difference that can make you waste unnecessary time.

Correct code:

```js
    "typeProperties": {
        "storedProcedureName": "[[dbo].[teststoredproc]"
    }
```

instead of

```js
    "typeProperties": {
        "storedProcedureName": {
            "value": "[[dbo].[teststoredproc]"
        }
    }
```